# Sum of 2 Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm able to sum 2 values in one multidimensional array and print using Console Application.That code below prints 2 sums of each multidimensional arrays. But what I need is,Printing the sum of 2 multidimensional arrays.I've cleaned the code up to be less complex.

```
        int[,] a = new int[2, 2];
        int[,] b = new int[2, 2];
        int[,] c = new int[2, 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter {0}. Mark of First lesson", i + 1, j + 1);
                a[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter {0}. Mark of Second lesson", i + 1, j + 1);
                b[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                c[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j];
                Console.WriteLine("{0}."+c[i, j],i+1+"The sum of 2 marks is:",j+1);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to do extra calculation for that. Its really very simple.

You can take two variable which will tell you the sum of each matrix and finally you can add them. Or If you want only the sum of two matrices then you can get that by one variable only.

So When you are filling your matrices just increment the respective sum by that value thats it.

```
public static void Main()
{

    int[,] a = new int[2, 2];
    int[,] b = new int[2, 2];
    int[,] c = new int[2, 2];

    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter {0}. Mark of First lesson", i + 1, j + 1);
            a[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            sum1 += a[i,j]; 
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter {0}. Mark of Second lesson", i + 1, j + 1);
            b[i, j] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            sum2 += b[i, j];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + (sum1 + sum2));


    //for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    //{
    //    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    //    {
    //        c[i, j] = a[i, j] + b[i, j];
    //        Console.WriteLine("{0}." + c[i, j], i + 1 + "The sum of 2 marks is:", j + 1);
    //    }
    //}
    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to this

```
 int[,] a = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
        int[,] b = new int[2, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 } } ;
        int[] c = { 0, 0 };
        int[] d = { 0, 0 };

        int k = 0;
        int l = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                c[k] =c[k]+ a[i,j];
            }
            k++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                d[l] = d[l]+ b[i, j];
            }
            l++;
        }
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < c.Length; i++)
            sum1 += c[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
            sum2 += d[i];

        int totalSum = sum1 + sum2;
        Console.WriteLine(totalSum);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The last loop?Looks like you have only changed j<1 to j<3.The j variable is there to say the amount of loop of print.

Comment: If you want to add up two dimesional arrays... rows are here 2 and columns are 3 so i should be less than 2 and j should be less than 3...If not this,please explain what are you trying to do

Comment: Actually I dont use the 3rd row,and I edited the code.Thanks for reminding that.But yeah thats not the thing I want.Let me explain:10+10 =20 , 30+30=60 then 20 + 60 =80.

Comment: so you mean if you have arrays like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] ..what is your output should be

Comment: [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]  => [[6],[15]] and [[6],[6]]  => [21] and [12] =>  21+12 => 33

Comment: @KorayBallı so, you want your final output as 33? thats it?

Comment: Yes thats what I exactly need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
```

This will run exactly once because 0 + 1 = 1 and 1 is not less than 1. In other words, it'll never actually do anything with the second row in the array. Change it to

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
```

and it'll work (see more details below).

Another thing to consider: you may need to clarify exactly how this operation is supposed to work. In this case, "sum" is actually really ambiguous. For example:

```
Array 1     Array 2
2           3
4           6
```

Should the result be

```
Array 3
5
10
```

(i.e. it works like vector addition) or should it be `15`? (It's easy enough to modify your code to work like the second one; in that case, you wouldn't use an inner `for` loop at all, just a counter storing which row you're adding).

A third possibility (and I seriously doubt that this is what you want) but you might be trying something like this:

```
Array 1 Sum     Array 2 Sum
6               9
```

Here's a code sample that may help:

```
private static void AddTwoArrays()
    {
        int size;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a size:");
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid int");
        }

        int[][] array1 = new int[size][];
        int[][] array2 = new int[size][];

        int sum = 0;

        int[] rowSum = new int[size];

        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            array1[i] = new int[size];
            array2[i] = new int[size];

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                array1[i][j] = random.Next(0, 5);
                array2[i][j] = random.Next(0, 5);

                // This is if you want to get the sum of every number contained in the array
                sum += array1[i][j];
                sum += array2[i][j];

                // This'll give row-by-row
                rowSum[j] += array1[i][j];
                rowSum[j] += array2[i][j];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum.ToString());
    }
```

It doesn't work exactly the same way as yours does but it could still serve as a useful example.

Comment: It doubles the result of each multidimensional array.I mean it prints same thing twice

Comment: @KorayBallı Please see my edit - it's not actually all that clear what operation you're trying to implement but I've given a couple of possibilities here. In any case, my original point is that the way you've done your loops makes no sense because it won't actually loop through the whole array, it literally does nothing with the second row so it's pointless.

Comment: Look at the third possiblity,Array 1 sum is 6 and Array 2 sums is 9.Now I need 6+9

Comment: @KorayBallı So, basically, what I said before - the answer should be 15?